# Table scroll by clicking and dragging horizontally and vertically with fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a table that the user can click and drag to scroll through it both horizontally and vertically, but keep the header fixed at the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag and scroll vertically using eventListeners. To keep the header fixed you can create a copy of the table and hide the body of one and hide the header of the other. Copying the whole table ensures that the widths stay the same. You can then make the header table scroll horizontally when the body table is scrolled horizontally.

```js
var tableBody = document.getElementById('scrollDragable');
var headerTable = document.getElementById('scrollDragableHeader');
var curDown = false
var oldScrollLeft = 0;
var oldScrollTop = 0;
var curXPos = 0;
var curYPos = 0;

tableBody.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
 if (curDown === true) {
   tableBody.scrollLeft = oldScrollLeft + (curXPos - e.pageX);
    headerTable.scrollLeft = oldScrollLeft + (curXPos - e.pageX);
    tableBody.scrollTop = oldScrollTop + (curYPos - e.pageY);
  }
})

tableBody.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
 curDown = true;
  curYPos = e.pageY;
  curXPos = e.pageX;
  oldScrollLeft = tableBody.scrollLeft;
  oldScrollTop = tableBody.scrollTop;
})

tableBody.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
 curDown = false;
})

//Ensures the header scrolls when the user uses the scrollbar
tableBody.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
   headerTable.scrollLeft = tableBody.scrollLeft;
})
```

```css
#scrollDragable {
  width: auto;
  height: 600px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  
  /* Prevent the text from highlighting when dragging */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#scrollDragableHeader {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
  /* Prevent the text from highlighting when dragging */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollDragableHeader">
<!--Create a table and hide the body but show the header -->
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th>Column4</th>
      <th>Column5</th>
      <th>Column6</th>
      <th>Column7</th>
      <th>Column8</th>
      <th>Column9</th>
      <th>Column10</th>
      <th>Column11</th>
      <th>Column12</th>
      <th>Column13</th>
      <th>Column14</th>
      <th>Column15</th>
      <th>Column16</th>
      <th>Column17</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody hidden>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="scrollDragable">

<!--Create a clone of the table and hide the header and show the body-->
<table>
  <thead style="visibility:collapse;">
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th>Column4</th>
      <th>Column5</th>
      <th>Column6</th>
      <th>Column7</th>
      <th>Column8</th>
      <th>Column9</th>
      <th>Column10</th>
      <th>Column11</th>
      <th>Column12</th>
      <th>Column13</th>
      <th>Column14</th>
      <th>Column15</th>
      <th>Column16</th>
      <th>Column17</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution, if you wanna make it perfect you should avoid dragging when someone releases the cursor outside the area. Check events at the end of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/9fvb8sdw/